# How add items to database with form and with another form to remove it in Drupal(Content type)?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have one form, that I created with content type. that add item to system like this:

[image]

and I want to remove like this

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Could you post your errors as text through editing this question?

Comment: You have to create a custom module and create forms for your purpose.